# Imagemagick exif кодировка текстовых данных

Tags: php, imagemagick, exif

При чтении *exif*-данных с помощью *imagemagick* в консоли некоторые текстовые данные имеют вид *ASCII*-последовательности.

**Пример:**

Запрос

```
identify -format %[exif:WinXP-Title] 1.jpg
```

Ответ

```
63, 4, 64, 4, 56, 4, 50, 4, 53, 4, 66, 4, 32, 0, 66, 4, 53, 4, 60, 4, 48, 4, 32, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0
```

Если в метаданных содержится только латиница, то проблем не возникает, но как только там появляются русские буквы, то вынуть их не выходит.

Заголовок из примера содержит кириллицу, но попытки извлечь эти данные ни к чему не приводят, вернее выводятся символы из краткой *ASCII*-таблицы.

Попытки изменить кодировку или установить локаль результата не дают.

Код извлечения символов:

```
$symbolList = preg_split('/,\s*/', $str);
foreach($symbolList as &$symbol)
    $symbol = chr($symbol);
```

результат:

```
?,,@,,8,,2,,5,,B,, ,
```

Меня очень смущает тот факт, что коды *ASCII* из примера имеют маленькие значения (явно не кириллица), возможно проблема в *imagemagick'е*, возможно он неверно извлекает данные? или эти значения нужно как-то конвертировать?

Метаданные корректны, поскольку во вьюверах корректно отображаются.

P.S. Пример изображения с *Exif*:

[image]

Comment: пример картинки содержащей такой *exif*, вероятно, совсем не помешал бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

из приложенной фотографии `identify` выдаёт такую информацию:

```
$ identify -format '%[EXIF:WinXP-Title]' 1.jpg
66, 4, 53, 4, 65, 4, 66, 4, 0, 0
```

с помощью `exiftool` я посмотрел, что это строка `тест`.

количество чисел, их парность, удвоенный ноль в конце — всё наводит на мысль о том, что выдача `identify` — это, возможно, строка в utf16, где символы кириллицы занимают по одному двухбайтовому знакоместу.

только значения байт переведены в десятичную систему счисления.

проверяю гипотезу:

```
$ echo -n 'тест' | iconv -t utf16 | hd
00000000  ff fe 42 04 35 04 41 04  42 04                    |..B.5.A.B.|
0000000a
$ identify -format '%[EXIF:WinXP-Title]' /tmp/1.jpg | \
sed 's/^/obase=16;/;s/,/;/g' | bc
42
4
35
4
41
4
42
4
0
0
```

ага! ну ооочень похожая последовательность. добавляю немного (весьма «топорного», т.к. «на скорую руку») *shell-fu*:

```
$ identify -format '%[EXIF:WinXP-Title]' /tmp/1.jpg | \
sed 's/^/obase=16;/;s/,/;/g' | bc | sed 's/^.$/0&/;s/^/\\\\x/' | \
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | xargs echo -ne | iconv -f utf16
тест
```

есть! гипотеза оказалась верной.

выходит, что `identify` не декодирует представленную в `utf16` строку, а выдаёт её побайтово, переводя значения байт в десятичную систему счисления.

---

**добавлено**

а набор чисел, упомянутый в вопросе, «переводится» так:

```
$ echo '63, 4, 64, 4, 56, 4, 50, 4, 53, 4, 66, 4, 32, 0, 66, 4, 53, 4, 60, 4, 48, 4, 32, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0' | \
sed 's/^/obase=16;/;s/,/;/g' | bc | sed 's/^.$/0&/;s/^/\\\\x/' | \
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | xargs echo -ne | iconv -f utf16
привет тема !
```

Answer (score 1):

Работающий метод для конвертации данных в нормальный вид.

$str - строка вида `66, 4, 53, 4, 65, 4, 66, 4, 0, 0` полученная из *exif*-данных

```
private function decodeString($str)
{
    if(preg_match('/^(?:(\d{1,3}),?\s*)+0,\s*0$/', $str) == false)
        return $str;

    $symbolList = array_reverse(preg_split('/,\s*/', $str));
    foreach($symbolList as &$symbol)
        $symbol = sprintf('%02x', $symbol);

    $symbolList[0] = 'fe';
    $symbolList[1] = 'ff';

    $retStr = '';
    $str =  trim(iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', hex2bin(join('', $symbolList))));
    for($i = mb_strlen($str) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
        $retStr .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1);

    return $retStr;
}
```